# Must an AVL tree satisfy the characteristics of a BST to be considered an AVL tree?

Tags: data-structures, tree, binary-tree, binary-search-tree, avl-tree

Or does AVL tree only characterize a tree where all subtrees have a height balance of at most 1 ?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about Computer Science. Also, I'd ecpect you to be able to search for this.

Comment: @MitchWheat- I actually think this is pretty tricky to search for. I've taught the shape of AVL trees outside of the context of BSTs in a discrete math course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically, the term AVL tree refers to the balanced binary search tree data structure. There's no reason you couldn't talk about AVL trees to refer to the *shape* of the tree rather than the data structure represented by that shape, and it is often useful to do so (for example, if you wanted to implement an order-statistic tree on top of an AVL tree structure).

Hope this helps!